# Bad Instruction Error when I try updating a variable from my ViewController

Tags: swift, variables, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am working on a Swift program that will calculate a user's burned calories and accordingly update a counter graph so that the user can visualize their progress. However I am having trouble actually updating my counter for the display because I am not sure how to exactly call a update a variable that exists inside another view controller.

So all my calorie calculations happen in the my main ViewController file, where I update labels with the necessary data.

I then attempt to pass the necessary calorie data to another view controller named CounterView, where I mean to update the count variable so that my graphic will react accordingly.

All I want to do, is update my `count` variable that exists in my CounterView, with data calculated within ViewController. I think my code makes sense and I know what I have to do, I just think my Syntax is wrong...Anyways any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Code for reference:**

Main ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//So that I can access the CounterView view controller
// I think this is where I am messing up...

var counterView: CounterView!

@IBOutlet weak var displayData: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pizzaData: UILabel!

var arrayImage : [UIImageView]?
var data = HKHealthStore()
var timer: NSTimer?
var track: Int = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("first")
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Asks the user to allow access to HealthKit data

    if let energyType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) {
        print("Test1")

        let setType = Set<HKSampleType>(arrayLiteral: energyType)
        data.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(setType, readTypes: setType, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.loadData()
                print("Test2")
                // Below code attempts to refresh the loadData function periodically

                self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(15, target: self, selector: Selector("loadData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            })

        })

    }
    print("Test3")

}



func notifyWatch(data:String){
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    if session.paired && session.watchAppInstalled {

        session.sendMessage(["data":data], replyHandler: { (dataReply) -> Void in
            print("It works")
            }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                print("An error has occured \(error.localizedDescription)")

        })
    }
}


var time: NSDate?

func fetch(completion: () -> Void) {
    time = NSDate()
    completion()
}



// Collect and load the data

func loadData() {

    let startDate = NSDate.distantPast()
    let endDate = NSDate()

    if let energyType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) {

        // Predicate so that we collect data from within the same day

        let timeFrame = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: .None)

        // Sort descriptor to get most recent data first

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

        // Execute query and gather Health data


        data.executeQuery(HKSampleQuery(sampleType: energyType, predicate: timeFrame, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor], resultsHandler: { (query: HKSampleQuery?, results: [HKSample]?, err: NSError?) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if err != nil {
                    // ERROR Occurred
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
                var calories = 0
                var pizzas = 0

                for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample]! {
                    // SUCCESS, use results here

                    print("Sample:", result)
                    print("Quantity", Int(result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit())), "Calories")

                    calories += Int(result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit()))
                    print("Pizzas", pizzas)
                    print(calories)



                }


                //Line where I get the Bad Instruction Error
                self.counterView.count += (calories%480)/480 * 360

                pizzas = Int(calories/480)



                self.displayData.text = "\(String(calories)) Calories"
                self.pizzaData.text = "Slices:\(String(pizzas))x"

                self.notifyWatch(self.pizzaData.text!)

            })

        }))

    }

}
```

Code from my CounterView:

```
var NoOfGlasses = 360
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

@IBDesignable class CounterView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var count: Int = 0 

@IBInspectable var outlineColor: UIColor = UIColor.brownColor()
@IBInspectable var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // 1
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

    // 2
    let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)

    // 3
    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 169

    // 4
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 2
    let endAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 2

    // 5
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
        radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,

        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: endAngle,
        clockwise: true)


    // 6
    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    counterColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()


    //Draw the outline

    //1 - first calculate the difference between the two angles
    //ensuring it is positive
    let angleDifference: CGFloat = 2 * π - startAngle + endAngle

    //then calculate the arc for each single glass
    let arcLengthPerGlass = angleDifference / CGFloat(NoOfGlasses)

    //then multiply out by the actual glasses drunk
    let outlineEndAngle = arcLengthPerGlass * CGFloat(count) + startAngle

    //2 - draw the outer arc
    let outlinePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
        radius: bounds.width/2 - 2.5,
        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: outlineEndAngle,
        clockwise: true)

    //3 - draw the inner arc
    outlinePath.addArcWithCenter(center,
        radius: bounds.width/2 - arcWidth + 2.5,
        startAngle: outlineEndAngle,
        endAngle: startAngle,
        clockwise: false)

    //4 - close the path
    outlinePath.closePath()
    let fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    outlineColor.setStroke()
    outlinePath.lineWidth = 5.0
    outlinePath.stroke()
    fillColor.setFill()
    outlinePath.fill()




    //Counter View markers

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //1 - save original state
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    outlineColor.setFill()
}
```

Comment: I don't see any place where `var counterView: CounterView!` gets assigned an object.  Is it supposed to be an IBOutlet?  (And `CounterView` isn't a controller.)

Comment: I've tried IBOutlet but I get the same error...

Comment: So how is it supposed to be connected to the view controller?

Comment: That's my question...I don't know the syntax how to do it :(

Comment: It's not a question of syntax (at least, mine isn't)...I'm asking where the `CounterView` is created and how you expect it to be linked to the controller.  If you tell me how the objects are supposed to relate to each other, figuring out syntax will be easy.

Comment: My app has one main view in the Storyboard which is controlled by the ViewController. This has a subview called the Counter View which is connected the CounterView class. As for how the ViewController and CounterView are directly connected...I don't think they are. I want this line of code in the ViewController: `self.counterView.count += (calories%480)/480 * 360` to connect to this line of code in CounterView: `@IBInspectable var count: Int = 0` so that I can draw my graphic using `let outlineEndAngle = arcLengthPerGlass * CGFloat(count) + startAngle`

Comment: Try declaring the `counterView` variable as an outlet.  Then connect it to the `CounterView` object in your storyboard by selecting your view controller and dragging from the outlet to the view, using the Connections Inspector.

Comment: Thanks! So I am no longer getting the Bad Instruction Error anymore, but my count variable is still not updating...do you have any ideas?

Comment: Print the result of `(calories%480)/480 * 360` and see what you're actually adding to the count.

Comment: I tested it and the calculation works...but when I say `self.counterView.count += (calories%480)/480 * 360`, XCode tells me that it's not allowed...

Comment: No...It just says "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ;" but that error makes no sense at all. Maybe it is regarding the placement of my call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106645/discussion-between-ahad-sheriff-and-phillip-mills).